# Stop submitting from javascript ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, submit, return

I'd like to stop a form submitting by thr result of an ajax request...
this is the code i tried to use:
The function chreg() should return a boolean given from the ajax request, but it doesn't!

Javascript:

```
function chreg() {

user = document.getElementById('nome').value;
passw1 = document.getElementById('passw1').value;
passw2 = document.getElementById('passw2').value;
mai = document.getElementById('mail').value;
dat = 'use='+encodeURIComponent(user)+'&pas='+encodeURIComponent(passw1)+'&pas2='+encodeURIComponent(passw2)+'&mail='+encodeURIComponent(mai);

htp = new XMLHttpRequest;
htp.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (htp.readyState == 4 && htp.status == 200){
        if (htp.responseText == "true"){
            alert('true');
        return true;
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('er2').innerHTML = '<br/><h3>'+tag_esc(decodeURIComponent(htp.responseText))+'</h3>';
        return false;
        }


    }
};
a = Math.random
  htp.open("POST","checklog.php?a="+a,true);
  htp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    htp.send(dat);   
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return chreg(this);">
<table id="tab2"><tr><td>

<label for="user1">Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="nome" /></label></td>      <td>
<label for="mail">Indirizzo e-mail: <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" /></label>   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td><label for="pass1">Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" id="passw1" />    </label></td>
    <td><label for="pass2">Password (conferma): <input type="password" name="pass2"  id="passw2" /></label></td></tr>
     <tr><td colspan="2"><br /><input type="submit" class="st" value="Registrati" /></td>    </tr>

</table>
<div id="er2"></div>
</form>
```

But it doesn't work!
Help
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to make it work as it stands because **AJAX is *asynchronous*** by default. That means that your `chreg` method initiates the request and returns *immediately*, before the request has completed and its result become known. This is a problem because you cannot return from `chreg` before the result is known since you need that result to know *what* to return.

One solution would be to make the request synchronous by changing the third parameter here:

```
// you will not need to set onreadystatechange at all

htp.open("POST","checklog.php?a="+a,false); // false = synchronous
htp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
htp.send(dat);   
if (htp.responseText == "true"){
    alert('true');
    return true;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('er2').innerHTML = '<br/><h3>'+tag_esc(decodeURIComponent(htp.responseText))+'</h3>';
    return false;
}
```

This is not the best solution because it might end up locking up the UI for the duration of the request, which is undesirable. However, going back to the asynchronous model (which does not have this problem) is going to be more involved because it requires you to do stuff "backwards":

1. Function `chreg` is called and makes the AJAX request; it *always* returns `false` (so the form is not submitted)
2. When the `onreadystatechanged` handler you installed detects that the AJAX is complete, it checks the response.
3. If the response is logically true (the form actually needs to be submitted) then use [`form.submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) to do it.

Comment: @user1296041: I just added two lines (including the one with `send`) to the example code -- did you try it this way and it didn't work?

Comment: I didn't reload this page so a didn't see the new code...
IT WORKS!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your success handler function returns either true or false but your main `chreg` method doesn't.

You need to return false in your `chreg` method to stop the form submitting.

```
    [...]
    htp.send(dat); 
    return false;
```

Since you're handling the form submission through ajax, you'll likely not want the form to do a postback atall.

Comment: thanks for answer, 
but if the function chreg returns false, it returns false also when the ajax response is true!
and the submitting stops!

Comment: You're using ajax which is asynchronous by nature.  Why do you want to submit the form when the ajax response is true? You're handling the form submission in the ajax request right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p>Please input a number.</p>

<input id="demo" type="text">

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
if(x==""||isNaN(x))
        {
        alert("Not Numeric");
        }
}
</script>
```