# Stop html submit button in js ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, xmlhttprequest, submit

I want to stop the submit button in the js function checkUni()

Usually in js you can just return false, but that it not gonna work in my case because its an asynchronous (ajax)function, so the outer function will return before the inner function is able to determine wether to return false or true.

Here is the js function:

```
function checkUni() {
 var URL = "http://localhost:8080/GradSchoolApp/test.jsp";
  var container = document.getElementById("container_ID"); //destination of returned data
  var request = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
  }
  request.open("GET", URL, true);

  request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        //SOME CODE
                    //IF <something> then STOP SUBMIT BUTTON
        container.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: found an answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165093/stop-submitting-from-javascript-ajax-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return false in the onclick listener.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="checkUni(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: See my updated answer. You just stop the submit process syncron and wait for the async stuff.

Comment: yeah, I've seen that answer a lot. The part I didn't get was how I was supposed to submit the button if true. But i found this:

document.<myform>.submit();

and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Your are welcome. Just don't forget to accept helpful answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the action of the form element to "#" which will have the same effect.